# help making a grid based game in java

Tags: java, 2d, gui

i'm trying to achieve a grid that you can move an character a set number of spaces on per turn, similarly to fire emblem or advance wars. instead of going for a tileset approach however, i want to have an invisible grid that contains all of the properties of each tile (such as movement penalty, combat bonuses while standing on the tile, etc) then just put a gui behind containing an image that lines up with all of the tiles. i'm not exactly sure how to approach this however so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you provide code you have written that didn't work, and explain why it didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Um... an invisible grid is one you represent in memory, but don't display.
Nothing stops you from representing whatever you like in memory and never displaying it! It's pretty easy to do nothing!

In memory you set up a 2D array of tiles, e.g.

```
Tile[][] tiles= Tile[ROW_COUNT][COL_COUNT];
```

I would suggest setting up some drawing logic to show the boundaries of the tiles while you are developing, that you can turn off with e.g. F1 key, so you can see how it will look in the final game.

Just render an image before/beneath everything else, each frame, and you should be good to go?